# How to find specific character with x times repeated, and after that character capture everything?

Tags: javascript

Have statement like `[[+pagetitle]] and [[++site_name]]`, needed separate and find each individually.

I expecting to get [[+pagetitle]] and [[++site_name]] separately with 2 different of course regexp.

Tried:
`\[{2}\+{1}.*?\]{2}`
`\[{2}\+{1}.+\]{2}`

What i currently achieved, is collecting everything. `\[{2}\+{1}.*?\]{2}` with capture same as + and ++ as the same, but they have different ideas behind, how to find each separate? Regex101 page https://regex101.com/r/uezzxc/1

I expecting to get [[+pagetitle]] and [[++site_name]] separately with 2 different of course regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\[{2}\+[^+]*?\]{2}` you can match `[[+pagetitle]]` and not `[[++site_name]]` because `[^+]` matches anything but a `+` sign.

To match `[[++site_name]]` and not `[[+pagetitle]]` you could use `\[{2}\+{2}.*?\]{2}`.

https://regex101.com/r/acgtj6/1